# Is a random walk i.i.d.?

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, random-walk, iid

Assuming that we have an AR(1) process:
$$X_t=\rho X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t,\quad\varepsilon\sim IIDN(0,1)$$
And further assuming that $\rho=1$ and $X_0=0$ we have a random walk process:
$$X_t=\sum_{i=1}^t\varepsilon_t$$

Is this process i.d.d.?
If yes/no why is that the case?

Comment: What do you mean by "Is this process i.i.d.?" Clearly $X_t$ and $X_{t+1}$ are not independent.

Comment: Hi @Rstrobaek. A random walk is not i.i.d. First of all, a random walk is non-stationary. Stationarity provides the 'identical' aspect of an i.i.d. Furthermore, a random walk exhibits dependency. To evoke something along the lines of independence, you would require the time series to exhibit something like weak dependency/ergodicity. However, as a comment, this is simply a sketch of the issue. I am sure you'll get a more complete answer

Comment: @EB3112, this should be an answer.

Comment: Hi @RichardHardy. I appreciate you saying so. However, @@Dave has provided a much more complete account than my scant version. However, I agree that intuition goes very far.

Comment: @EB3112 Your comment addresses points not raised explicitly in my answer and would be worth having in an answer.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it is unclear what is meant with 'is this process i.i.d?'. The example by Dave shows that there's correlation, but with another interpretation one could get non-correlated results (eg repeatedly generate random walks and each random walk will be independent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at a simulation.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2023)

# Length of each time series
#
N <- 100

# Number of times to simulate
#
R <- 1000

# Function to create the time series 
# (I don't remember the syntax for the built-in function)
#
time_series <- function(rho, x0, N, mu = 0, sigma = 1){
  
  # Blank vector to hold the time series
  #
  ts <- rep(NA, N)
  
  # Declare the first value
  #
  ts[1] <- x0
  
  # Autoregressive series with additive noise
  #
  for (i in 2:N){
    ts[i] <- rho*ts[i - 1] + rnorm(1, mu, sigma)
  }
  
  return(ts)
}

# Data frame to hold the fifth and sixth values of the time series
#
d <- data.frame(ts5 = rep(NA, N), ts6 = rep(NA, N))

# Simulate R-many time series, storing the 5th dnd 6th values
#
for (i in 1:R){
  ts <- time_series(1, 0, N)
  d[i, ] <- c(ts[5], ts[6])
}

# Plot the 5th and 6th values against each other to note the correlation
#
ggplot(d, aes(x = ts5, y = ts6)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Time 5") +
  ylab("Time 6")
```

[image: time series scatterplot]

The visual evidence convinces me of a correlation. We can also do a formal hypothesis test of the correlation via `cor.test(d$ts5, d$ts6)` to get a p-value $\approx 0$.

This makes sense. By defining the time series as autoregressive, you are specifying the sixth point as being equal to the fifth point plus some noise, so there is certainly going to be some dependence between the two points.

If you want to be rigorous about the math, calculate the covariance between consecutive points, knowing that a random variable will be correlated with a linear combination of itself and the Gaussian error term.

(My selection of the 5th and 6th points was arbitrary but sufficient to show the lack of independence. If the 5th and 6th points are correlated, then the time series is not IID.)

Also, the "identical" part of $IID$ is violated. As you go further out in the series, the variance increases, as each subsequnt time step adds an additional noise term.

Comment: Here is another simulation, creating a similar image, but it uses iid multivariate normal distributed variables `n = 10^3; x = MASS::mvrnorm(n, c(0,0), matrix(c(4,4,4,5),2)); plot(x)`.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I'm not following the connection to the time series question, other than your plot looking like mine. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The vectors that you simulated can be considered as iid vectors. To show that, I simulated them directly from the distribution $$\begin{bmatrix}x_5\\x_6\end{bmatrix} \underset{iid}{\sim} \mathcal{N} \left( \boldsymbol{\mu} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma} = \begin{bmatrix}4 & 4 \\ 4 & 5\end{bmatrix}  \right)$$